# How to prevent Rake test to call task db:test:prepare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Every time I want to run Rake test the task db:test:prepare is being called and it rebuilds my test environment database from schema.rb and migrations. What I would like to achive is to disable the call of db:test:prepare when I want to test make Rails application. Is it possible without modifying Rails gem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a solution I've seen around:

In your Rakefile:

```
Rake::TaskManager.class_eval do
  def remove_task(task_name)
    @tasks.delete(task_name.to_s)
  end
end
```

In `lib/tasks/db/test.rake`:

```
Rake.application.remove_task 'db:test:prepare'

namespace :db do
  namespace :test do 
    task :prepare do |t|
      # rewrite the task to not do anything you don't want
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I like this. With this you don't have to install any plugin and it works well. However, what about if I want to use prepare method in the future? Is it possible to keep it only remove it from Rake running queue?

Comment: In that case, I guess you'd have to use this method to rewrite `test:units`, `test:functionals`, and `test:integration` so that they don't inherit from the `db:test:prepare` task.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tested this, but you could probably change `remove_task` to: 

`def rename_task(task_name, new_task_name)
  @tasks[new_task_name] = @tasks.delete(task_name)
end`

You'll still have to rewrite `db:test:prepare` because the test tasks will still run it.

Comment: mckeed that's what the plugin mentioned in another answer does. But I don't need to keep the old task around.

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin that takes care of this for you: [override_rake_task](https://github.com/eugenebolshakov/override_rake_task).  Here is a quick usage example:

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    override_task :prepare do; end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For some older version of rails - you can place `Rake::Task['db:test:prepare'].clear` at the end of your Rakefile