# How do I create a persistent table in a Rails app's test database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that references the [TMY3 meteorological dataset](http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2005/tmy3/), which is a ton of different hourly weather observations for over 1000 different sites.

I downloaded the entire dataset and sucked the columns I need into a local table that is indexed by site, which makes it nice and fast in dev and in production.

However, the indexing takes a good 5 minutes, which makes it a HUGE pain to load in every time for tests.  This table never changes, so I'd like to just load it once into my testing environment and then leave it there to run the rest of my tests against.  All my other models and tables are standard rails dealies that get factoried or mocked as needed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you seeding with db:seed? How are you loading those data for test?

Comment: I didn't know about db:seed - right now I'm just not loading (or testing) that model, which is brand-spanking new.  I load the table into my dev and production environments by piping a previously mysqldumped file into mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might see if [this question about db:test:prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097845/how-to-prevent-rake-test-to-call-task-dbtestprepare) applies to your situation.

Comment: I ended up going with this approach - actually overriding db:test:purge and just dropping each non-persistent table individually instead of dropping the entire database and recreating it.

There is a bit of additional complexity because I have to now figure out how to get the persistent database out of schema.rb, or at least not get loaded in the test environment.

Comment: Subsequent question & answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752667/keep-a-table-out-of-schema-rb-during-migrations

Basically, had to add the following line to environment.rb:

ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = ["table_name"]

Answer (score 2):

For the model that you need to not get torn down at test time, put it in a separate database for testing purposes.  Only the test database that is loaded from database.yml is cleared and rebuilt from the development database's schema.

```
class PersistModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    PersistModel.establish_connection(
       :adapter  => "sqlite3",
       :database => "db/persist.sqlite3"
    )
end
```

This class will never have it's database cleared out.

You could probably get creative and have a test version of your real model that establishes a different connection.

```
class WeatherTest < Weather
    WeatherTest.establish_connection(
       :adapter  => "sqlite3",
       :database => "db/weather.sqlite3"
    )
end
```

That way all of your functions from the "real" model are available to your test version.

Comment: This is definitely an elegant way to to this, but I need to join the persistent table to a couple of non-persistent ones.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it myself but could one of the caching plugins offer a solution ?
[Advanced Caching - from the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#advanced-caching/)