# Limit the schema.rb to specific tables within a large database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to limit the schema.rb to specific tables?

I'm building a rails app on an Oracle database with hundreds of tables but my app only creates a few tables. When I look in the schema I see all the tables.

Comment: Ew! Another good reason why, IMHO, schema.rb is somewhat useless. Is it perhaps an option to just not use schema.rb? I.e. don't check it in to your repo and just ignore that it exists for your day-to-day work?

Comment: Does your app use any tables that it did not create?  If the app is only using tables that it created consider using a seperate database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep a table out of schema.rb during migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752667/keep-a-table-out-of-schema-rb-during-migrations)