# Why Rspec is cleaning database on 'bundle exec rake spec'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, testing, rspec

I don't understand strange thing. 
I have table in my Postgresql database with 200 items

```
psql: \c app_test; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items -->200
```

After installing rspec `rspec-rails gem` in rails and executing

```
RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake spec
```

...

```
psql: \c app_test; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items -->0
```

Seems to be it is cleaning (purge) DB. Why?

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-nav', '>= 0.2.3'
  gem 'pry-rails', '>= 0.2.2'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
end
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'


RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"


  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

end
```

Comment: Answer should be somewhere in your rails_helper/spec_helper files.

Comment: Added files source

Comment: Hm, no database_cleaner? Interesting.

Comment: It was. But I have deleted it from Gemfile and ```RAILS_ENV=test bundle install```

Comment: And it keeps deleting the records? At a glance, I don't see how it could happen (except having something like `Item.delete_all` somewhere in your tests).

Comment: I have deleted all tests but it still deletes all records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196588/discussion-between---and-sergio-tulentsev).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698117/run-dbtestload-dbtestpurge-without-resetting-database

Comment: Also you can run `bundle exec rspec spec`. That one does not purge the db.

Comment: ```RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec spec``` worked, thank you